# Term(s) to refer to bias in randomized, open-label designs

Tags: terminology, bias, clinical-trials

Patients who are enrolled to clinical studies may have a preference for an investigational treatment, and agree to be randomized in hopes they receive that treatment. When the treatment administration is very difficult, and a placebo is not possible/ethical, an open-label design is permitted. That is: patients know what treatment they're receiving. If patients know they are assigned to receive the less-preferred treatment, they may be less likely to attend visits, receive treatment, or report any adverse events.

As what may we refer to this type of bias?